# How to 'isolate' root effectively?

Tags: calculus

Base on a problem from Apostol Calculus : Given an equation , to 'isolate' a root of that equation , we need to identify an interval [a,b] so that this interval contain only that root and no others , with an aid of **Bolzano's Theorem** , try to find it!. He gave me 3 equation: $$3x^4 - 2x^3 - 36x^2 + 36x - 8 = 0$$ $$2x^4 - 14x^2 + 14x - 1 = 0$$ $$x^4 + 4x^3 + x^2 - 6x + 2 = 0$$

I tried to find all roots of it but I couldn't. And my solution manual just plug $x$ from -4 to 4 into the first equation , but this approach is not efficient and for me like a gamble . So can we have another approach to isolate those roots without know exactly what they are ?

This is what Bolzano's Theorem state : **let $f$ be continuous at each point of a closed interval [a,b] , assume $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs. So there is at least one c in (a,b) such that $f(c) = 0$**

Comment: There are many ways. I think the most effective for real roots is [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem), but see also *[Geometrical properties of polynomial roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots)* and *[Real-root isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation)*.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find all rational roots, and the GCD of the polynomial and its derivative to find multiple roots.

Comment: Note that Sturm's theorem is not the most efficient, although it can be the easiest to taught. [Vincent's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent%27s_theorem) can give a faster algorithm

Comment: About rational root theorem, it's a great theorem ! I've learnt it once in "The art of problem solving" volume 2 . About the others , I think I shall look it up when a suitable time comes . Anyways, thanks !

Comment: @NDB Apparently Sturm is not the most efficient on computer. I'll have a look at the linked article on Wikipedia, i.e. [Collins & Akritas](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800205.806346), as well as [Collins & Loos](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800205.806319). Both are free to read, as is [everything on the ACM site before 2001](https://www.acm.org/articles/bulletins/2022/april/50-years-backfile).